# VHDL 4-display counter on a Nexys 3 (0000 to 9999)

Tags: vhdl, display, counter, spartan

I'm triyng to implement a 4 display counter (0 to 9999) on a Nexys 3. However, when I load the bit file, all displays remain at 0. It seems like variables a,b,c,d; which control individual digits, stay at 0, but that doesn't happen in the simulation. Xilinx throws these warnings:

```
WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <a<1:3>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <contador10000>.
    WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <b<1:3>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <contador10000>.
WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <c<1:3>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <contador10000>.
WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <d<1:3>> (without init value) have a constant value of 0 in block <contador10000>.
WARNING:Xst:1426 - The value init of the FF/Latch a hinder the constant cleaning in the block contador10000.
   You should achieve better results by setting this init to 1.
    WARNING:Xst:1426 - The value init of the FF/Latch a hinder the constant cleaning in the block contador10000.
   You should achieve better results by setting this init to 1.
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <ca_6> (without init value) has a constant value of 1 in block <contador10000>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <ca_2> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <contador10000>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <ca_1> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <contador10000>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

And, if I set an initial value other than 0, it will be on the displays for a short instant before returning to 0.

I'm trying a 4 process approach:

1. The clock, which generates two pulses (one for the anode switching, one for the actual count)
2. A process which switches rapidly between anodes in order to display different numbers at the "same time"
3. A process to asign the value of each individual digit to the established display.
4. A process to do the count 0000 to 9999 and save the values in 4 digits (a,b,c,d)

This is my code.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity contador10000 is
    port(
        clk,reset   :   in  std_logic :='0';
        led             :   inout   std_logic := '0';
        an              :   out std_logic_vector(0 to 3);
        ca              :   out std_logic_vector(0 to 6)
        );
end contador10000;

architecture cuenta of contador10000 is

type display is array(1 to 4) of std_logic_vector(0 to 3);
constant DISPLAYS : display := ("0111","1011","1101","1110");

type    digit   is array(0 to 9) of std_logic_vector(0 to 6);
constant DIGITS : digit := ("0000001","1001111","0010010","0000110","1001100","0100100","0100000","0001111","0000000","0001100");

signal i            : integer RANGE 0 to    6000000 :=  0;
signal j        : integer RANGE 0 to        1000    := 0;
signal a,b,c,d : integer RANGE 0 to 9               := 0;

signal q : std_logic                := '0';
signal x : integer RANGE 1 to 4 :=1;

begin

process(clk)
    begin
if(clk'event AND clk='1') then      i   <=  i + 1;
    j   <= j + 1;

    if i = 6000000 then

        led <=  not led;
        i       <=  0;

    end if;

    if j = 1000 then

        q   <= not q;
        j   <= 0;

    end if;

end if;
end process;

process(reset,led)
begin
    if(reset'event and reset='1') then
    a <= 0;
    b <= 0;
    c <= 0;
    d <= 0;
else
if(led'event and led='1') then
    if a = 9 then
        a <= 0;

        if b = 9 then
            b <= 0;

            if c = 9 then
                c <= 0;

                if d = 9 then
                    d <= 0;

                else d <= d + 1;
                end if;

            else c <= c + 1;
            end if;

        else b <= b + 1;
        end if;

    else 
        a <= a + 1;
    end if;

end if;
end if;
    end process;

process(q)
    begin
    if q'event and q='1' then
    an <= DISPLAYS(x);


if x = 4 then x <= 1;
else x <= x + 1;
end if;
end if;

end process;

process(q)
begin

if(q'event and q='1') then

case x is

when 1 => ca <= DIGITS(d);
when 2 => ca <= DIGITS(c);
when 3 => ca <= DIGITS(b);
when 4 => ca <= DIGITS(a);
end case;
end if;
end process;

end cuenta;
```

Comment: I'm not following everything you're trying to do, but will give you a little advice. It's much cleaner to run everything on a single clock. Your clock dividing for "`led`" and "`q`" should probably become single strobes with all processes running on "`clk`" only. Try that first and see if that makes the tools happier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DONE. The reset wasn't working properly, so the 4 digit signals (a,b,c,d) were always at 0. Just by removing the `reset'event and reset='1'` line I was able to see actual numbers on the Nexys 3.

Comment: This is the repo of the code, if you're interested. https://github.com/vzalberto/contadorvhdl